# Java File Download - Downloaded file size is always zero Kb

Tags: java, file, download

I have written a java controller which handles any download request from the server. My files are present in the server however I am getting 0 kB file downloaded every time. The file is getting downloaded but the size is always 0 Kb. Please help me. Here is my code -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/downloadFile/{docId}")
    public void getDownloadFile(@PathVariable(value = "docId") Integer docId, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String userName = getUserName();
        try {
            DocVault documentsVault = documentsVaultRepository.findDocumentAttachment(docId);
            String fileName = documentsVault.getDocumentName();
            int customerId = documentsVault.getCustomerId();

            Map<Integer, String> customerInfo = cspUtils.getCustomersInfo(userName);
            Set<Integer> customerIds = customerInfo.keySet();
            for (int custId : customerIds) {
                if (custId == customerId) {
                    String path = env.getProperty("doc.rootfolder") + File.separator + documentsVault.getFileName();
                    service.downloadFile(fileName, path, response);
                } else {
                    logger.info("Customer not linked to user");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Implementation -

```
public void downloadFile(String fileName, String path, HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
            File downloadFile = new File(path);
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

            response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

            // get output stream of the response
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am not getting any exceptions. Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. What I figured out was there was a problem with my Content Disposition header. I was passing only the file name without extension. When I passed the full file name then it worked perfectly. Size and Extension of the file were proper.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
```

Remove this. The container will set it automatically.

```
int bytesRead = -1;
```

You don't need to initialize this variable. It gets assigned in the very next line.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Now the size is okay. But the file type is just getting downloaded as 'file' instead of .txt, .pdf, .doc, etc. Can you help? Previously also this issue was there.

Comment: then - maybe check (through dev console or fiddler) what `Content-Disposition` header is returned. I see you set it correctly, but you should check what's the real value returned to the browser

Comment: @HarshitGupta The 'save as' business depends entirely on what you are sending as the `Content-disposition`.